# Change the selected value from combo-box in edit form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to make use of the existing insertion form as edit form for user to make any changes in existing record, the following coding is getting the value which passing from another form

```
<?php $error=""; if (isset($_GET['id'])) { $id=$_GET['id']; include checkpo.php';
if (checkpono($id)==true && checkpostatus($id)==true) {
    include 'db.php';
    $select_PO=mysql_query("SELECT pono, bu, dept, dor, quote1, quote2, quote3 FROM tb_po WHERE pono = '". $id ."' AND postatus !='Approved' AND pono NOT IN (SELECT pono FROM tb_postatus)", $conn);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($select_PO);
            if ($count == 1) {
                $row=mysql_fetch_array($select_PO);
            }
mysql_close($conn);

}
else {
    die("The PO No. ". $id ." does not allow to edit <a href='searchpo.php'>Return</a> to previous page.");
}}
```

but i do not know how to set the selected value in combo-box and allow the user make changes.
sorry, what i want is that, the values (from mysql) in combo-box "dept" are "HR", "Admin", Finance" and "PR" and when the record passed to this form, the selected value (i.e "HR") in combo-box "dept" which is posted in mysql before, so when user select the pull down menu, they can change the value either from "HR", "Admin", Finance" and "PR".

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    $query = "SELECT dept FROM tb_dept";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    ?>
    <select id="dept" name="dept" style="width: 126px">
    <?php
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $line['dept'];?>"> <?php echo $line['dept'];?></option>
    <?php }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: which value you want to make selected?

Comment: @SameerShaikh I think he wants the current value of the data to be selected in his edit form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an if condition inside the option tag like this

**`<option value="<?php echo $line['dept'];?>" <?php if($line['dept']==$matching variable){ echo 'selected'}?>> <?php echo $line['dept'];?></option>`**

The selected attribute will show the option selected when the value is matched

Comment: sorry, what i want is that, the values (from mysql) in combo-box "dept" are "HR", "Admin", Finance" and "PR" and when the record passed to this form, the selected value (i.e "HR") in combo-box "dept" which is posted in mysql before, so when user select the pull down menu, they can change the value either from "HR", "Admin", Finance" and "PR".

Comment: @jchan Yes this is the exact what i understand you can compare the posted data with the mysql data which is creating the combo-box and then you can show the selected value in the box and user will be able to select from the other options and when you will save the page after edit it will be updated in the database again